# Django ORM annotate Sum calculation wrong and its multiplying by number of entry, it's wired

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am going through a wired situation in Django ORM. It is returning a wrong calculation of sum and unexpectedly it is multiplied by the number of entries which I don't want, it's behave completely wired.

These are my models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Purchase(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='person_purchase'
    )

    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)



class Consumption(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='person_consumption'
    )

    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

This is my query:

```
person_wise_payable = Person.objects.annotate(
            difference=ExpressionWrapper(
                Coalesce(Sum('person_purchase__amount'), Value(0)) - Coalesce(Sum('person_consumption__amount'), Value(0)),
                output_field=FloatField()
            ),
        )

    for i in person_wise_payable:
        print(i.difference, i.name)
```

I am trying to find out the difference between person wise Purchase and Consumption.

For example, i have 3 person, `foo, doe, jhon`

**and these are their entry**

```
Purchase models entries:
foo = 5
doe = 2
doe = 3
doe = 3


Consumption models entries:

foo = 1
foo = 2
foo = 2
doe = 1
doe = 1
jhon = 2
```

So you see above,

```
foo total purchase is 5
doe total purchase is 8
jhon total purchase is 0 (coz, no entry of him)
```

and

```
foo total consumption is 5
doe total consumption is 2
jhon total consumption is 2
```

So expected output/difference if we subtract the `consumption` from `purchase`

```
foo : 5 - 5 =   0
doe: 8 - 2 =   6
jhon: 0 - 2 =   -2
```

I hope you got the point what i want to do and what is expected output.

```
foo 0, doe 6 and jhon -2
```

But the problem is, My current query not returning the output like this above, it is returning very very much wired, see the wired result below.

```
-2.0 jhon
10.0 doe
10.0 foo
```

Can anyone help me how can I get it done correctly? I am struggling with for last few days, couldn't achieve this yet

Comment: If you make multiple JOINs, teh they act as a multiplier, since you make a query `SELECT SUM(some_col) FROM some_table LEFT OUTER JOIN other_table LEFT OUTER JOIN yet_another_table`, so the `some_col` is repeated.

Comment: Exactly why do you need two models in the first place? Perhaps you can make one model where a purchase has a positive amount, and a consumption a negative one?

Comment: I want to keep two models for purchase and consumption, coz, consumption has difference usecase too in my business logic, I want tow models anyway

Comment: I think you mean WEIRD instead of WIRED lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make multiple JOINs, teh they act as a multiplier, since you make a query

```
SELECT SUM(purchase.amount) - SUM(consumption.amount)
FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase
LEFT OUTER JOIN consumption
```

so the *same* `purchase.amount` is repeated that many times as there are related `consumption`s, and the *same* `consumption.amount` is repeated that many times as there are related `purchase`s.

You can solve this with a subquery, for example with:

```
person_wise_payable = Person.objects.annotate(
    difference=Coalesce(Subquery(
        Purchase.objects.filter(
            person=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('person').annotate(
            sum=Sum('amount')
        ).values('sum')[:1]
    ), Value(0)) - Coalesce(Subquery(
        Consumption.objects.filter(
            person=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('person').annotate(
            sum=Sum('amount')
        ).values('sum')[:1]
    ), Value(0))
)
```